# Asking for reference for the relationship between vaccine openness and education levels ( beyond COVID-19)

Tags: reference-request, nonexpert

I am looking for a reference about the link between vaccine openness and education levels beyond COVID-19. I found a paper mentioned the link between vaccine openness and education but stick with COVID-19 of [Robertson 2021](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0889159121001100).
I am not sure this exchange is a place to post this question, if not, please let me know or move this question on behalf of me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search on [Google Scholar and restrict the range to end in 2019](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=1990&as_yhi=2019&q=vaccine+openness+education+level&btnG=), thus avoiding all Covid-19 related literature.

Some results for the range 1990-2019, keywords "vaccine openness education level":

[Lee et al. (2017): Personality and demographic correlates of New Zealanders’ confidence in the safety of childhood vaccinations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264410X17313099?casa_token=3yOUll1BtBcAAAAA:BGuFe554OaLkgFOQZZpI5RKPYcgirxMPWhgJeqV3j6cB-4qsXBeXQFb_R6E2VlQl2kJXB_zm0EQ)

[Browne et al. (2015): Going against the Herd: Psychological and Cultural Factors Underlying the ‘Vaccination Confidence Gap’](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0132562)